# Scroll ListView to show footer

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which displays search results.  When a search is being performed, I add a footer to the ListView which indicates that a search is in progress.  I'd like to programmatically scroll my ListView to the bottom so the footer is visible to the user.  Ideas?

My app is targeted to 2.1+

Comment: Why not display it independently of the list? It sounds a little clunky to scroll the list when it doesn't really involve the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method to scroll the ListView to bottom.

```
private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
    myListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Taken from [Listview Scroll to the end of the list after updating the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606530/listview-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-list-after-updating-the-list)

Comment: Thank you for citing the source! Also in many cases the Runnable may not be necessary `myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);` might be enough.

Comment: A little modification to above answer, instead of using myListAdapter.getCount() we can use myListView.getCount().

Comment: You might also want to try `myListView.smoothScrollToPosition(myListView.getCount() - 1)`. This way, you're not forced into selecting the last row. Plus, you get some smooth, beautiful scrolling! (:

Comment: This doesn't work, scrolls just to last child, excludes footer.

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
lv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    lv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
                    lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
                }
            });
```