# How to set ListView Scroll position to bottom in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I know this question is asked several times before but my situation is bit different from other questions.

I have a listview and initially i want to set the scroll position to the bottom of the list.

I have try 2 ways.

1st one

```
mCommentListView.setSelection(mAdaptor.getCount()-1);
```

2nd one

```
mCommentListView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mCommentListView.setSelection(mAdaptor.getCount()-1);
    }
});
```

So my problem is both of above code working properly with the emulator **but it is not working with the real device.**

What have i missed?

Comment: Where are you invoking those method calls? Post more complete code.

Comment: from Asynactask OnPostExecute().

Comment: Try this: `mCommentListView.setSelection(mCommentListView.getCount() - 1);`

Comment: And when is the AsyncTask started? Post your code for the Activity and the list adapter.

Comment: @JoelFernandes i tried but no luck :(

Comment: @kaluwila Did you try that with the first method? Also, try giving a number and see if it is working that way. Ex; `mCommentListView.setSelection(5);`

Comment: @ JoelFernandes yeah you got a point hmm it is not going to work with any number it will always set to first item.but anly in the device working fine with the emulater

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606530/listview-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-list-after-updating-the-list

Comment: @kaluwila Hmm that's strange. Can you post all the code that's related to the ListView?

Comment: @Shayan pourvata that is what i have already tried.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this. the below code is working fine for me.

give time delay 500 for load listview then call setselection method.

```
commentslistview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        commentslistview.setSelection(commentsarraylist.size());
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Ok Ganash i got it. thanks a lot to other people also giving me a great help.

Answer (score 8):

Did you set these in your **ListView**?

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Comment: yes i tried this on also but if you set android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" it will scroll to bottom always i dont need that i want that for the first time only.

Answer (score 2):

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
srollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,scrollView.getBottom());
                        }
                    });
                }
        });
```

Comment: hyy what is the srollView? hear i am dealing with a listview

Comment: scrollView is object of a ScrollView here .But science u are dealing with a list view you can try to to have a the listview in side of a scrollView.

Comment: @ Biplab putting a listview inside scrollview is not a good  practice in android anyway thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

:D I just set:

```
mListView.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
```

And my Layout

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tb_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    tools:ignore="NestedScrolling" >
</ListView>
```

SET

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:stackFromBottom="true"
```

Hope it works fine with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
mCommentListView.getChildAt(mCommentListView.getChildCount() - 1).requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
commentslistview.smoothScrollToPosition(commentsarraylist.size() -1);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I got what OP was asking, but solution gives an animation scroll To last position.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10851424)

Comment: @DennisKriechel Why not?