# Move at the same speed as listview scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working on an Android app. In my activity, I have a View A and a ListView B. 
I'm wondering if there is a way when I scroll the ListView B, the View A can move together (in the same direction, same speed, same distance)?

Thank you

Comment: take look on this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606530/listview-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-list-after-updating-the-list

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is a way when I scroll the ListView B, the View
>   A can move together (in the same direction, same speed, same
>   distance)?

Yes You can achieve that by adding header to your listview.

You can also achieve the footer same way.

For Example:

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
    String[] names = new String[] { "Linux", "Windows7", "Eclipse", "Suse",
        "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone", "Linux", "Windows7",
        "Eclipse", "Suse", "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone" };
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    listView.addFooterView(footer);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
        android.R.id.text1, names));

  }
}
```