# add view over keyboard android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard, emoji

in my android application I have a chat activity ,I use this code from [android-chat-starter](https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter)

the problem is in the emulator everything works fine , I tested it in many types of emulators (api >18 , api =18 , api <18) 
but in testing in actual device it behaves like in this image

[image]

the emoji view shows above the keyboard

here is the code I use to show the emoji view

```
  private void showEmojiPopup(boolean show) {
    showingEmoji = show;

    if (show) {
        if (emojiView == null) {
            if (getActivity() == null) {
                return;
            }
            emojiView = new EmojiView(getActivity());

            emojiView.setListener(new EmojiView.Listener() {
                public void onBackspace() {
                    chatEditText1.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 67));
                }

                public void onEmojiSelected(String symbol) {
                    int i = chatEditText1.getSelectionEnd();
                    if (i < 0) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    try {
                        CharSequence localCharSequence = Emoji.replaceEmoji(symbol, chatEditText1.getPaint().getFontMetricsInt(), AndroidUtilities.dp(20));
                        chatEditText1.setText(chatEditText1.getText().insert(i, localCharSequence));
                        int j = i + localCharSequence.length();
                        chatEditText1.setSelection(j, j);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Error showing emoji");
                    }
                }
            });


            windowLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            windowLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
            Log.d(TAG ,Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " ");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                windowLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
            } else {
                windowLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
                windowLayoutParams.token = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken();
            }
            windowLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
            Log.d("emoj",WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE + "");
        }

        final int currentHeight;

        if (keyboardHeight <= 0)
            keyboardHeight = App.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("emoji", 0).getInt("kbd_height", AndroidUtilities.dp(200));

        currentHeight = keyboardHeight;

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) App.getInstance().getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        windowLayoutParams.height = currentHeight;
        windowLayoutParams.width = AndroidUtilities.displaySize.x;

        try {
            if (emojiView.getParent() != null) {
                wm.removeViewImmediate(emojiView);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            wm.addView(emojiView, windowLayoutParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        if (!keyboardVisible) {
            if (sizeNotifierRelativeLayout != null) {
                sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, currentHeight);
            }

            return;
        }

    } else {
        removeEmojiWindow();
        if (sizeNotifierRelativeLayout != null) {
            sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (sizeNotifierRelativeLayout != null) {
                        sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


}

 @Override
public void onSizeChanged(int height) {

    Rect localRect = new Rect();
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(localRect);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) App.getInstance().getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (wm == null || wm.getDefaultDisplay() == null) {
        return;
    }


    if (height > AndroidUtilities.dp(50) && keyboardVisible) {
        keyboardHeight = height;
        App.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("emoji", 0).edit().putInt("kbd_height", keyboardHeight).commit();
    }


    if (showingEmoji) {
        int newHeight = 0;

        newHeight = keyboardHeight;

        if (windowLayoutParams.width != AndroidUtilities.displaySize.x || windowLayoutParams.height != newHeight) {
            windowLayoutParams.width = AndroidUtilities.displaySize.x;
            windowLayoutParams.height = newHeight;

            wm.updateViewLayout(emojiView, windowLayoutParams);
            if (!keyboardVisible) {
                sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (sizeNotifierRelativeLayout != null) {
                            sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, windowLayoutParams.height);
                            sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.requestLayout();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

my androidmanifest.xml contains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />


     <activity
        android:name=".ConversationShowActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_conversation_show"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.exampel.myapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

here is my conversation show xml

```
<com.example.myapp.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                     android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            xmlns:fontawesometext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:bootstrap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            tools:context="com.example.myapp.ConversationShowActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/errorLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:visibilty="invisible"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"

        android:text="Error loading conversation messages, Click here to try again"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#ffff4314"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
     </LinearLayout>

   <ProgressBar
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/convProgressBar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/conv_header"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/conv_avatar"
        android:src="@drawable/blank_avatar4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aboudi"
        android:id="@+id/conv_user_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/conv_avatar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/conv_online"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/conv_online"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="conv_online"
        android:id="@+id/conv_online"
        android:layout_below="@+id/conv_user_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/conv_avatar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/conv_avatar"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileFavBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/heart_bg"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/profilegiftBtn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.FontAwesomeText
        android:id="@+id/profileFavText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontawesometext:fa_icon="fa-heart-o"
            android:textColor="#B94309"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profilegiftBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/accept_btn_bg"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/profileReportBtn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.FontAwesomeText

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontawesometext:fa_icon="fa-gift"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileReportBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/report_btn_bg"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/profileBlockBtn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.FontAwesomeText

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontawesometext:fa_icon="fa-info"

            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileBlockBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/refuse_btn_bg"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.FontAwesomeText

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontawesometext:fa_icon="fa-remove"

            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chat_list_view"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:divider="@drawable/chat_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:layout_below="@id/conv_header"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_footer_border_top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cant_send_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="You cant contact this member right now"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:background="#ff4409"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_msg_panel_smiles" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/emojiButton" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chat_edit_text1" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/enter_chat1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/emojiButton"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/emojiButton"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/enter_chat1"
            android:hint="Type your message here .."

            android:singleLine="false"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"

            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp" />

        <ImageView android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                   android:id="@+id/enter_chat1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chat_edit_text1"
                   android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                   android:paddingStart="13dp"
                   android:paddingRight="17dp"
                   android:paddingEnd="17dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_send" />

    </RelativeLayout>



  </LinearLayout>
</com.example.myapp.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout >
```

here is my emojiview

```
public class EmojiView extends LinearLayout {
 private ArrayList<EmojiGridAdapter> adapters = new      ArrayList<EmojiGridAdapter>();
private int[] icons = {
        R.drawable.ic_emoji_recent,
        R.drawable.ic_emoji_smile,
        R.drawable.ic_emoji_flower,
        R.drawable.ic_emoji_bell,
        R.drawable.ic_emoji_car,
        R.drawable.ic_emoji_symbol };
private Listener listener;
private ViewPager pager;
private FrameLayout recentsWrap;
private ArrayList<GridView> views = new ArrayList<GridView>();

public EmojiView(Context paramContext) {
    super(paramContext);
    init();
}

public EmojiView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet) {
    super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
    init();
}

public EmojiView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet, int paramInt) {
    super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet, paramInt);
    init();
}

private void addToRecent(long paramLong) {
    if (this.pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    ArrayList<Long> localArrayList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    long[] currentRecent = Emoji.data[0];
    boolean was = false;
    for (long aCurrentRecent : currentRecent) {
        if (paramLong == aCurrentRecent) {
            localArrayList.add(0, paramLong);
            was = true;
        } else {
            localArrayList.add(aCurrentRecent);
        }
    }
    if (!was) {
        localArrayList.add(0, paramLong);
    }
    Emoji.data[0] = new long[Math.min(localArrayList.size(), 50)];
    for (int q = 0; q < Emoji.data[0].length; q++) {
        Emoji.data[0][q] = localArrayList.get(q);
    }
    adapters.get(0).data = Emoji.data[0];
    adapters.get(0).notifyDataSetChanged();
    saveRecents();
}

private String convert(long paramLong) {
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        if (i >= 4) {
            return str;
        }
        int j = (int)(0xFFFF & paramLong >> 16 * (3 - i));
        if (j != 0) {
            str = str + (char)j;
        }
    }
}

private void init() {
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 0; i < Emoji.data.length; i++) {
        GridView gridView = new GridView(getContext());
        //  if (AndroidUtilities.isTablet()) {
        //     gridView.setColumnWidth(AndroidUtilities.dp(60));
        // } else {
        gridView.setColumnWidth(AndroidUtilities.dp(45));
        // }
        gridView.setNumColumns(-1);
        views.add(gridView);

        EmojiGridAdapter localEmojiGridAdapter = new EmojiGridAdapter(Emoji.data[i]);
        gridView.setAdapter(localEmojiGridAdapter);
        //  AndroidUtilities.setListViewEdgeEffectColor(gridView, 0xff999999);
        adapters.add(localEmojiGridAdapter);
    }

    setBackgroundColor(0xff222222);
    pager = new ViewPager(getContext());
    pager.setAdapter(new EmojiPagesAdapter());
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = new PagerSlidingTabStrip(getContext());
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    tabs.setShouldExpand(true);
    tabs.setIndicatorColor(0xff33b5e5);
    tabs.setIndicatorHeight(AndroidUtilities.dp(2.0f));
    tabs.setUnderlineHeight(AndroidUtilities.dp(2.0f));
    tabs.setUnderlineColor(0x66000000);
    tabs.setTabBackground(0);
    LinearLayout localLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    localLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    localLinearLayout.addView(tabs, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
    ImageView localImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
    localImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_emoji_backspace);
    localImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    localImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_emoji_bs);
    localImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (EmojiView.this.listener != null) {
                EmojiView.this.listener.onBackspace();
            }
        }
    });
    localLinearLayout.addView(localImageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(AndroidUtilities.dp(61), LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    recentsWrap = new FrameLayout(getContext());
    recentsWrap.addView(views.get(0));
    TextView localTextView = new TextView(getContext());
    localTextView.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.NoRecent));
    localTextView.setTextSize(18.0f);
    localTextView.setTextColor(-7829368);
    localTextView.setGravity(17);
    recentsWrap.addView(localTextView);
    views.get(0).setEmptyView(localTextView);
    addView(localLinearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, AndroidUtilities.dp(48.0f)));
    addView(pager);
    loadRecents();
    if (Emoji.data[0] == null || Emoji.data[0].length == 0) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
}

private void saveRecents() {
    ArrayList<Long> localArrayList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    long[] arrayOfLong = Emoji.data[0];
    int i = arrayOfLong.length;
    for (int j = 0; ; j++) {
        if (j >= i) {
            getContext().getSharedPreferences("emoji", 0).edit().putString("recents", TextUtils.join(",", localArrayList)).commit();
            return;
        }
        localArrayList.add(arrayOfLong[j]);
    }
}

public void loadRecents() {
    String str = getContext().getSharedPreferences("emoji", 0).getString("recents", "");
    String[] arrayOfString = null;
    if ((str != null) && (str.length() > 0)) {
        arrayOfString = str.split(",");
        Emoji.data[0] = new long[arrayOfString.length];
    }
    if (arrayOfString != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfString.length; i++) {
            Emoji.data[0][i] = Long.parseLong(arrayOfString[i]);
        }
        adapters.get(0).data = Emoji.data[0];
        adapters.get(0).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void onMeasure(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
    super.onMeasure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(paramInt1), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(paramInt2), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}

public void setListener(Listener paramListener) {
    this.listener = paramListener;
}

public void invalidateViews() {
    for (GridView gridView : views) {
        if (gridView != null) {
            gridView.invalidateViews();
        }
    }
}

private class EmojiGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    long[] data;

    public EmojiGridAdapter(long[] arg2) {
        this.data = arg2;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return data[i];
    }

    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view;
        if (imageView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(EmojiView.this.getContext()) {
                public void onMeasure(int paramAnonymousInt1, int paramAnonymousInt2) {
                    setMeasuredDimension(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(paramAnonymousInt1), View.MeasureSpec.getSize(paramAnonymousInt1));
                }
            };
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (EmojiView.this.listener != null) {
                        EmojiView.this.listener.onEmojiSelected(EmojiView.this.convert((Long)view.getTag()));
                    }
                    EmojiView.this.addToRecent((Long)view.getTag());
                }
            });
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Emoji.getEmojiBigDrawable(data[i]));
        imageView.setTag(data[i]);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        if (observer != null) {
            super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        }
    }
}

  private class EmojiPagesAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.IconTabProvider {

    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup paramViewGroup, int paramInt, Object paramObject) {
        View localObject;
        if (paramInt == 0) {
            localObject = recentsWrap;
        } else {
            localObject = views.get(paramInt);
        }
        paramViewGroup.removeView(localObject);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return views.size();
    }

    public int getPageIconResId(int paramInt) {
        return icons[paramInt];
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup paramViewGroup, int paramInt) {
        View localObject;
        if (paramInt == 0) {
            localObject = recentsWrap;
        } else {
            localObject = views.get(paramInt);
        }
        paramViewGroup.addView(localObject);
        return localObject;
    }

    public boolean isViewFromObject(View paramView, Object paramObject) {
        return paramView == paramObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        if (observer != null) {
            super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        }
    }
}

public static abstract interface Listener {
    public abstract void onBackspace();
    public abstract void onEmojiSelected(String paramString);
  }
}
```

the problem happens when the keyboard is visible ,but if it's not visible the emoji view works fine

Comment: It should look like whatsapp or other messangers , it works well on emulators I tested it in many apis with virtual keyboard,but on my device the emojiview don't replace the keyboad and it comes above it

Comment: I want the emoji view popup instead of being above the keyboard , I want it to be over the keyboard ,in emulators I tested it works fine but not in actual device

Comment: yes you are right , the code I use should do that ,but it doesn't work in actual device

Comment: my device is alcatel one touch idol , android 4.1 and api 16 , but in emulator with api 16 it works

Comment: try adding Gravity.FILL to your window params

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, as far for Android 5.0 (dont know after) theres no way to get the keyboard height. So you can't use this value to position your View.

But, you can use the softKeyboard relayout to do what you want, by using softKeyboard (at the Activity manifest) with a value of "resize" will make your root layout View to be resized to the size of the remaining screen space. By positioning your view at the bottom will make it exactly on top of the keyboard.

PS: Also, your root view needs its height value to be match_parent instead of anything else (or you will need to deal in hard other ways)

Maybe you mean you want to replace the keyboard location instead of being on "top of it" (NORTH?), in this case, you should use a CustomView that extends View and not use the EditText that does open the keyboard for you

Comment: PS: you need a view that matchs_parent height to it get resized

Comment: the problem is that I tested it in a lot of emulators with different apis and it works there but not on the device

Comment: The manifest is correct, the problem is that the Emojis is a Popup and not a View in the layout, so it will not get invalidated after relayout.

Comment: You need to add the Emojis view inside the Activity layout instead of a Popup

Comment: but it will be also above the keyboard not replacing it

Comment: OHH, you mean you want to replace the keyboard location instead of being on "top of it" (NORTH?), in this case, you should use a CustomView that extends View and not use the EditText that does will open the keyboard for you.

Comment: in the code I provided when you click on the emoji face beside the edit text ,it toggle between the keyboard and the emojiview , would you mind check my question I provided the library I am using to achieve that

Comment: Cant you force the keyboard to HIDE when you request the Emoji to OPEN? and vice-versa.

Comment: I tried it but it hide the keyboard and the emojipopup on the same time

Comment: that's what I am trying to know from here ?, would you mind testing the library I provided in a device and check if it will work with you or not ?

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos  I'm sure you can get the height of the keyboard in 5.0

Comment: The ViewTreeObserver solution does not work on resize-behaviour=pan, only for resize, that does cause other effects on the layout.

The touch try approach is a hack that shouldnt work across all different devices.

Answer (score 8):

You will have to hide the keyboard while showing window of emoji via:

`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edText.getWindowToken(), 0);`

where edText is the edittext you have currently focus on.

EDIT:
This is my code merged into yours.you can give it a try.

```
    private void showEmojiPopup(boolean show) {
    showingEmoji = show;

    if (show) {
        if (emojiView == null) {
            if (getActivity() == null) {
                return;
            }
            emojiView = new EmojiView(getActivity());

            emojiView.setListener(new EmojiView.Listener() {
                public void onBackspace() {
                    chatEditText1.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 67));
                }

                public void onEmojiSelected(String symbol) {
                    int i = chatEditText1.getSelectionEnd();
                    if (i < 0) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    try {
                        CharSequence localCharSequence = Emoji.replaceEmoji(symbol, chatEditText1.getPaint().getFontMetricsInt(), AndroidUtilities.dp(20));
                        chatEditText1.setText(chatEditText1.getText().insert(i, localCharSequence));
                        int j = i + localCharSequence.length();
                        chatEditText1.setSelection(j, j);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Error showing emoji");
                    }
                }
            });


            windowLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            windowLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
            Log.d(TAG ,Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " ");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                windowLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
            } else {
                windowLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
                windowLayoutParams.token = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken();
            }
            windowLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
            Log.d("emoj",WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE + "");
        }

        final int currentHeight;

        if (keyboardHeight <= 0)
            keyboardHeight = App.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("emoji", 0).getInt("kbd_height", AndroidUtilities.dp(200));

        currentHeight = keyboardHeight;

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) App.getInstance().getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        windowLayoutParams.height = currentHeight;
        windowLayoutParams.width = AndroidUtilities.displaySize.x;

        try {
            if (emojiView.getParent() != null) {
                wm.removeViewImmediate(emojiView);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            wm.addView(emojiView, windowLayoutParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        if (!keyboardVisible) {
            if (sizeNotifierRelativeLayout != null) {
                sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, currentHeight);
            }

            return;
        }

    } else {
        removeEmojiWindow();
        if (sizeNotifierRelativeLayout != null) {
            sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (sizeNotifierRelativeLayout != null) {
                        sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


}

 @Override
public void onSizeChanged(int height) {

    Rect localRect = new Rect();
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(localRect);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) App.getInstance().getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (wm == null || wm.getDefaultDisplay() == null) {
        return;
    }


    if (height > AndroidUtilities.dp(50) && keyboardVisible) {
        keyboardHeight = height;
        App.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("emoji", 0).edit().putInt("kbd_height", keyboardHeight).commit();
    }


    if (showingEmoji) {
//code to hide keyboard
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edText.getWindowToken(), 0);
//end
        int newHeight = 0;

        newHeight = keyboardHeight;

        if (windowLayoutParams.width != AndroidUtilities.displaySize.x || windowLayoutParams.height != newHeight) {
            windowLayoutParams.width = AndroidUtilities.displaySize.x;
            windowLayoutParams.height = newHeight;

            wm.updateViewLayout(emojiView, windowLayoutParams);
            if (!keyboardVisible) {
                sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (sizeNotifierRelativeLayout != null) {
                            sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, windowLayoutParams.height);
                            sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.requestLayout();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where exactly I should put this code , can you use my code for open emoji and put your code in it's place there

Comment: this code hides the keyboard then show the emoji and close the emoji after that (

Comment: this code i have added is to hide the keyboard..
I think the size of emoji window is dependent directly on keyboard. so if keyboard height is 0 when it is hidden then emoji window might be of zero size.

Comment: FYI i added the code after your program calculated height of keyboard.
You can calculate keyboard height by this:

 `public void GetVirtualKeybrdHeight() {
  root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
     public void onGlobalLayout() {

      Rect r = new Rect();
      root.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
      Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      int height = display.getHeight();
      int screenHeight = root.getRootView().getHeight();
      keyboradSize = screenHeight - (r.bottom - r.top);
     }});}`

Comment: I updated my quesion with a method called onSizeChanged ,maybe it's responsible for that ?

Comment: you can try playing with these two lines

`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edText.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Comment: you can add them in onsizechanged

Comment: how ? cause I don't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: i have updated the answer plz see if that works for you

Comment: The 2 lines are responsible for hiding keyboard. you should add them in your code when you have already calculated keyboard's height then put those lines there. Because if you would hide the keyboard before calculating its height, the height will give zero.

Comment: what result are you getting?

Comment: the same as before , would you mind check the library I provided , I use the same code there

Comment: the method you posted is from library..??
can you give me the link please

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom EditText and disable showing the keyboard by override *onCheckIsTextEditor*. Refer code below:

```
  public class NoKeyBoardEditText extends EditText {

   @Override      
   public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {   
      return false;     
   }   

  }
```

Comment: and how I can show the keyboard again when the user wants to use the keyboard instead of the emojiview

Comment: use the emoji keyboard to show normal keyboard.I know implementing own keyboard is lot of overhead but if you not finding anything else this is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: would you mind check my question with the library I used andoid-starter-chat , I use the code there to open the emojiview , the only solution now is to hide the keyboard instead of replacing it with the emojiview , but I can't do that , would you mind check the code there and helping me to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this for creating View over softKeyboard.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/my_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- Your content here If edittext here then change the layout_height="wrap_content" on your EditText to layout_height="0dip" and let the weight handle it. --> // like your edittext or something.

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/yourkeyboardlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Your yourkeyboardlayout items here -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note :

Remove this line from your code if you have used it.
`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS‌​_VISIBLE);`

In your manifest :

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Make sure that you have adjusted your SoftInputMode to AdjustResize.

For more info regarding SoftInputmode refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

And if you don't want to show to your layout when keyboard is down then just hide that layout.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this on my application, I have extracted from the library
https://github.com/chathudan/KitKatEmoji
I recommend you use the library is very complete and easy to implement. In the example of the library is its easy use. If not, pull something like this:

```
   private void showKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    keyboard.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

.

```
  private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mActivity.getCurrentFocus()
            .getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

.

```
protected void changeEmojiLayout() {
    final InputMethodManager keyboard =    
(InputMethodManager)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//      keyboard.showSoftInput(message, 0);
    if (isEmojiVisible && !isKeyBoardVisible) {
        btnEmoji
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_insert_emoticon_black_24dp);
        btnCamara.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnGaleria.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        emojiIconsCover
                .setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        isEmojiVisible = false;
        mShowEmojiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                inputMsg.requestFocus();
                keyboard.showSoftInput(inputMsg, 0);
                checkKeyboardHeight(parentLayout);
            }
        }, 100);

    } else if (isEmojiVisible && isKeyBoardVisible) {

    } else if (!isEmojiVisible && isKeyBoardVisible) {
        hideKeyboard();
        mShowEmojiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btnEmoji
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_vp_keypad);
                btnCamara.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnGaleria.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                emojiIconsCover
                        .setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                isEmojiVisible = true;
            }
        }, 100);
    } else if (!isEmojiVisible && !isKeyBoardVisible) {
        btnEmoji
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_vp_keypad);
        btnCamara.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnGaleria.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        emojiIconsCover
                .setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        isEmojiVisible = true;
    }
}
```

.

```
private void checkKeyboardHeight(final View parentLayout) {

    parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    parentLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                    int screenHeight = parentLayout.getRootView()
                            .getHeight();
                    int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom);

                    if (previousHeightDiffrence - heightDifference > 50) {
 //                         popupWindow.dismiss(); TODO
  //                               
btnEmoji.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_vp_smileys);
                        emojiIconsCover.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                    }
                    previousHeightDiffrence = heightDifference;
                    if (heightDifference > 100) {
                        isKeyBoardVisible = true;
 //                            changeKeyboardHeight(heightDifference);
                    } else {
                        isKeyBoardVisible = false;
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem when I added emoji's to my app.
I found a way to show Emoji's on top of Softkeyboard using **PopUpWindow**.

EmojiOverKeyboard

```
public class EmojiOverKeyboard extends PopupWindow {

private int keyBoardHeight = 0;
private Boolean pendingOpen = false;
private Boolean isOpened = false;
OnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener;
View rootView;
Context mContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param rootView  The top most layout in your view hierarchy. The difference of this view and the screen height will be used to calculate the keyboard height.
 * @param mContext The context of current activity.
 */
public EmojiOverKeyboard(View rootView, Context mContext){
    super(mContext);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.rootView = rootView;
    View customView = createCustomView();
    setContentView(customView);
    setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    //default size
    setSize((int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.keyboard_height), LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
/**
 * Set the listener for the event of keyboard opening or closing.
 */
public void setOnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener(OnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener listener){
    this.onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Use this function to show the emoji popup.
 * NOTE: Since, the soft keyboard sizes are variable on different android devices, the
 * library needs you to open the soft keyboard atleast once before calling this function.
 * If that is not possible see showAtBottomPending() function.
 *
 */
public void showAtBottom(){
    showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
}
/**
 * Use this function when the soft keyboard has not been opened yet. This
 * will show the emoji popup after the keyboard is up next time.
 * Generally, you will be calling InputMethodManager.showSoftInput function after
 * calling this function.
 */
public void showAtBottomPending(){
    if(isKeyBoardOpen())
        showAtBottom();
    else
        pendingOpen = true;
}

/**
 *
 * @return Returns true if the soft keyboard is open, false otherwise.
 */
public Boolean isKeyBoardOpen(){
    return isOpened;
}

/**
 * Dismiss the popup
 */
@Override
public void dismiss() {
    super.dismiss();
}

/**
 * Call this function to resize the emoji popup according to your soft keyboard size
 */
public void setSizeForSoftKeyboard(){
    rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

            int screenHeight = getUsableScreenHeight();
            int heightDifference = screenHeight
                    - (r.bottom - r.top);
            int resourceId = mContext.getResources()
                    .getIdentifier("status_bar_height",
                            "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                heightDifference -= mContext.getResources()
                        .getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
            if (heightDifference > 100) {
                keyBoardHeight = heightDifference;
                setSize(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, keyBoardHeight);
                if(isOpened == false){
                    if(onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener!=null)
                        onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener.onKeyboardOpen(keyBoardHeight);
                }
                isOpened = true;
                if(pendingOpen){
                    showAtBottom();
                    pendingOpen = false;
                }
            }
            else{
                isOpened = false;
                if(onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener!=null)
                    onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener.onKeyboardClose();
            }
        }
    });
}

private int getUsableScreenHeight() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        return metrics.heightPixels;

    } else {
        return rootView.getRootView().getHeight();
    }
}

/**
 * Manually set the popup window size
 * @param width Width of the popup
 * @param height Height of the popup
 */
public void setSize(int width, int height){
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
}

private View createCustomView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_over_keyboard, null, false);

    return view;
}


    public interface OnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener{
        void onKeyboardOpen(int keyBoardHeight);
        void onKeyboardClose();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RelativeLayout rootView;
private ImageButton showPopUp;
private EditText inputText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootview);
    showPopUp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showPopUp);
    inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);

    // Give the topmost view of your activity layout hierarchy. This will be used to measure soft keyboard height
    final EmojiOverKeyboard popup = new EmojiOverKeyboard(rootView, this);

    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.keyboard_background));
    popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.EmojiPopupAnimation);

    //Will automatically set size according to the soft keyboard size
    popup.setSizeForSoftKeyboard();

//If the emoji popup is dismissed, change emojiButton to smiley icon
    popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            changeEmojiKeyboardIcon(showPopUp, R.drawable.emoticon_upload_drawable);
        }
    });



    //If the text keyboard closes, also dismiss the emoji popup

    popup.setOnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener(new EmojiOverKeyboard.OnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyboardOpen(int keyBoardHeight) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyboardClose() {
            if (popup.isShowing())
                popup.dismiss();
        }
    });


//         To toggle between text keyboard and emoji keyboard keyboard(Popup)
    showPopUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //If popup is not showing => emoji keyboard is not visible, we need to show it
            if (!popup.isShowing()) {

                //If keyboard is visible, simply show the emoji popup
                if (popup.isKeyBoardOpen()) {
                    popup.showAtBottom();
                    changeEmojiKeyboardIcon(showPopUp, R.drawable.keyboard_variant);
                }

                //else, open the text keyboard first and immediately after that show the emoji popup
                else {
                    inputText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    inputText.requestFocus();
                    popup.showAtBottomPending();
                    final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(inputText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    changeEmojiKeyboardIcon(showPopUp, R.drawable.keyboard_variant);
                }
            }

            //If popup is showing, simply dismiss it to show the undelying text keyboard
            else {
                popup.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
     }

    private void changeEmojiKeyboardIcon(ImageView iconToBeChanged, int drawableResourceId){
        iconToBeChanged.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);
    }

}
```

ContentLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eceff1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#e4e7e9"
    ></LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#545e60"
    android:text="Show your Emoji's here"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:backgroundTint="#4db6ac"
        android:src="@drawable/emoticon_happy"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use my [sample github project](https://github.com/imidhuntv/View-Over-Keyboard-Android) for reference.

Comment: so you example is to show popup over keyboard ,but how can I use it in my code would you mind check my code and adapt it with your code ?

Comment: No dude. You checkout my code and run it also. That's exactly what you are looking for. I have commented all necessary areas. The problem with your code is that your emojiView extends LinearLayout. I extend emojiView (EmojiOverKeyboard) with PopupWindow. And hence it can stay over the Keyboard.

Comment: so the problem now is that the emojiview extends from linear layout , I updated my question with the emojiview class , what changes do I need to make there so it will work fine

Comment: Okay. I guess I understand the problem. You copy my code and create a PopUpWindow like that. Put your emojiView (layout containing emojis) into the  PopUpWindow. ie, setContentView(emojiView). do it in the PopUpWindow constructor. Call the required listeners (to listen to emoji click and all) also in the constructor. Remove those code for finding keyboard height and to hide/show emojiview from your code, since I already added that.

Comment: If you still don't understand you better go and have a look at this code. This is exactly what you want. https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

Comment: I changed to the emojicon library . but the same issue happened 
check this please https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/issues/20

Comment: when does that happen? Is it on some specific devices?

Comment: yes , on emulator it works fine , can't figure out what is the problem ,however whatsapp ,telegram are working fine on my device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96143/discussion-between-wonderkid-and-remon-amin).

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

It worked :). Add below two lines in your list view

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/chat_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"
    android:divider="@drawable/chat_divider"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"


    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >

</ListView>
```

[You can view it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606530/listview-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-list-after-updating-the-list)

Comment: I think your answer is not related to the question