# How to set scroll position at last after update adapter notifydatasetchanged in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here some snippet of my code. when first time RecyclerView create I have to used **recyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatDetailModels.size()-1);** and its working but after add item in array list and notifyDataSetChanged for adapter its not goes to bottom automatically I have also try some other functions but its not work for me.

```
  chatDetailModels.add(chatDetailModel);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606530/listview-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-list-after-updating-the-list

Comment: Which LayoutManager are you using?

Comment: please let me know link help you or not  and have you solve your problem.

Comment: problem solved by change recycle view version v7:23.1.1 other version have bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use Latest `Recyclerview` Version.
And then call-

```
 recyclerview.smoothscrolltoposition(arraylist.size()-1);
```

after you set adapter.